# wordpress site | All-in-one-cufon IE Issue

Tags: plugins, php, jquery, javascript

I have a site where i'm using the [All-In-One Cufon (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/all-in-one-cufon/), but having some issues getting it to render properly in IE.

The website: [removed]

The Problem: It works fine so far in Firefox and other browsers like Chrome. Even in internet explorer the first time the site loads it works fine but when I refresh the page or visit any other pages by clicking a link on the site it stops working (The text is still visible but cufon rendering doesn't work) :o

I have been trying to fix this since the past day without any success. I'm not 100% sure but I think it used to work fine awhile back but I just recently noticed this odd behavior and have no clue what could be making this happen.

My first thought was a conflict of a plugin, but I tried disabling ALL the plugins except the cufon and it still does the same thing.

Is anyone aware / experienced similar issue with their websites? and knows the solution?

Comment: I just tried removing the adsense code in my sidebar and after doing that it started working :o i'm confused why this is happening. I dont want to remove the adsense code. Any help? :(

Comment: One comment on your question: please don't shorten urls in your question. Its not necessary, and knowing where you're being directed to helps people feel more comfortable clicking a link.

Comment: @goldenapples - sorry i wasnt sure as i didn't want it to be indexed by search engines i avoided placing my site url directly.

Comment: Voting to close this question. This is not a WordPress related issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to have been resolved in the latest Release Candidate of IE9.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the following errors on your page:

*SCRIPT16387: Invalid pointer* (cufon.yui.js, line 121 character 39)

which corresponds to the pointer document.defaultView.getComputedStyle

I can't see what exactly is happening, but there's another message about the character encoding of your site: "HTML1114: Codepage iso-8859-1 from (HTTP header) overrides conflicting codepage utf-8 from (META tag)" Might want to check into that and make sure you have the correct document encoding.

Comment: thanks for your reply but i dont have the slightest idea what going on :( i just checked my header.php source to see how the encoding was set and i couldn't find any issues with it, i'm posting below:

`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />`

Comment: what tool / plugin are you using to detect these errors? i am using web developer addon and firebug but can't see any of these errors :(

Comment: @Zubair1 - I only saw those errors in the web developer console under IE9. Firebug on Firefox didn't pick them up. Using WP's charset shouldn't give you problems, but it looks like maybe something is conflicting with it? Does it work any better if you set your charset in WP to UTF-8?

Comment: @Zubair1 - Nevermind, it looks like it already is set to UTF-8, and something else is overriding it. Can't really see what though, although this looks like a fairly common conflict in IE. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589206/sifr-problem-in-ie-document-defaultview-getcomputedstyle for ex. Also, there are a number of bugs reported on the jQuery lists about that problem. Does updating to the current jQuery release (1.5.0) fix it for you?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, i can't seem to find any working solutions, i guess the issue is with IE9 itself (btw sorry i failed to mention that the problem only occurs in IE9 which is still in beta stages). The only possible solution i see is either i remove my adsense code from the site or force IE9 to behave like IE8. But i would rather skip both. I guess i'll leave it as it is for now.